# How to keep InArray validator when set inputFilter for Select Element in Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a form with a select element which contain by default an InArray validator.
If i set inputFilter like this:

```
$form->setInputFilter(new ProductListInputFilter());
```

I lost the InArrayValidator on the Select element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165467/zend-2-default-inarray-validator-of-select-element-gets-lost?rq=1